# Why overriding a generic method requires same bounds?

Tags: java, jls

For normal(non-generic) method, the sub-method is required to be override-equivalent with erasure of parent's method.

But for generic method, the sub-method is required to have **same type paraments**, which means **having same bounds** for every argument, for example:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public abstract <T> T example( Map<String, Integer> map) throws Exception;
}
public class Son1 extends Parent {
// this could work
    @Override
    public <T> T example(Map<String, Integer> map) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}

public class Son2 extends Parent {
// and this couldn't work
    @Override
    public <T> T example(Map map) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
public class Son3 extends Parent {
// and this could work
    @Override
    public Object example(Map map) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I could find where this check done([hasSameBounds](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11u/blob/master/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Types.java#L3240-L3241)).

Why doesn't Son2 work? Is there any description in JLS?

Comment: No, overriding a method with an argument type of `Map<String, Integer>` with a method which has argument type `Map` is always a problem - it always results in a "raw type". Raw types are only there for backward compatibility with pre-Java 1.5 code. Combining raw types with a generic type parameter in a method as in `public <T> T example(Map map)` does not make sense at all (as raw types only exist for code that doesn't understand generics) and is rejected.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt the situation of Son3 is for backward compatibility, and it has been described in JLS. But I can't find why Son2 cannot work, and Son1 can in JLS. That's the question.

Answer (score 0):

[*The **erasure** of the signature*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2-120) of *`Parent`*'s *`T example( Map<String, Integer> map)`* is *`T example(Map map)`*.

The signature of *`Son2`*'s *`T example(Map map)`* is ***the same as the erasure*** of the signature of *`Parent`*'s  *`T example( Map<String, Integer> map)`*. That makes the two signature's „[***override-equivalent***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2-130)“.

> „*…Why doesn't Son2 work?…*“

*`Son2`*'s doesn't work because of its *override-equivalence* to *`Parent`*'s.

> „*…Is there any description in JLS?…*“

Yes. There is…

> ### [*§8.4.2 Method Signature*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2-200)
>
> …
>
> ***It is a compile-time error to declare two methods with override-equivalent signatures in a class.***
>
> #### *Example 8.4.2-1. Override-Equivalent Signatures*
>
> ```
> class Point {
>     int x, y;
>     abstract void move(int dx, int dy);
>     void move(int dx, int dy) { x += dx; y += dy; }
> }
> ```
>
> *This program causes a compile-time error because it declares two `move` methods with the same (and hence, override-equivalent) signature. This is an error even though one of the declarations is `abstract`*.
>
> …